# "!" while defining text for asp.net control - for example a checkbox text

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular

I have come across the following code while troubleshooting an issue. I am not sure why someone would prefix "!" mark to the text "Forgot your password?" for the control. I am not an experience asp.net dev.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnPassReminder" runat="server" CssClass="SmallLink"
                    CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnPassReminder_Click">!Forgot your password?
                </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Angular and asp.net webforms is a bit of an odd mix in my opinion

Comment: If the `!` is disappearing it is either being done serverside in a custom event or client side via javascript.  Have you checked the HTML as rendered to the page using View  Source (not developer tools) to see if the `!` makes it as far as the browser as part of the ASP.net response?

Comment: thanx Jon P, I did use View Source, didn't see "!" there. Actually i am trying to understand what is the purpose of adding "!". As it disappears for all controls except one. I just wanted to confirm this is not something Asp.net/Angular syntax related. I know ASP.net + Angular is an odd mix.

Comment: From the small amount of code available, it is impossible to tell. It isn't a normal asp.net webform behavior. What happens if you remove the `!`? Do you have any access to the `.cs` files to see if there is anything happening in the `pre-render` event.  If the `!` is not appearing in the HTML source then it is happening server-side, but via some custom behavior.

Comment: unfortunately,  nope, no access to .cs file. Yes, this is strange behaviour. We've asked original developer of the software about this. but many thanks to provide more details in regards to troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason from an ASP.NET perspective (e.g. it is not an accessKey), it could be used by the font as an icon or replaced elsewhere, but there is not enough code to confirm this.

Comment: all other controls have the "!" mark at the start of the text. but it is not there when I see the webpage in browser. this is a software for which we don't have much access to full code. so i can't see where the code is written to strip off the "!" when the page renders. I just wanted to make sure if this is an asp.net thing to define text with "!" ?

Comment: also, the software is using angular code. but what i understand is the code snippet is purely asp.net code and it has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: It is most certainly **NOT** an asp.net thing to define text with an `!` .